# Regex for checking a line inside a code block

Tags: regex

I have a haproxy service startup script that looks like below:

```
case "$1" in
    start)
        echo -n "Starting haproxy "
        ## Start daemon with startproc(8). If this fails
        ## the return value is set appropriately by startproc.
        haproxy_check
        /sbin/startproc $HAPROXY_BIN -D -f $HAPROXY_CONF -p $HAPROXY_PID
        # Remember status and be verbose
        rc_status -v
        ;;
    stop)
        echo -n "Shutting down haproxy "
        ## Stop daemon with killproc(8) and if this fails
        ## killproc sets the return value according to LSB.

        /sbin/killproc -TERM $HAPROXY_BIN

        # this is additional forcing kill command to ensure that all processes are stopped.
        /usr/bin/killall -9 $HAPROXY_BIN || true
        # Remember status and be verbose
        rc_status -v
        ;;
    try-restart|condrestart)
        ## Do a restart only if the service was active before.
        ## Note: try-restart is now part of LSB (as of 1.9).
        ## RH has a similar command named condrestart.
        if test "$1" = "condrestart"; then
                echo "${attn} Use try-restart ${done}(LSB)${attn} rather than condrestart ${warn}(RH)${norm}"
        fi
        $0 status
        if test $? = 0; then
                # we us reload here for a graceful restart during update
                $0 reload
        else
                rc_reset        # Not running is not a failure.
        fi
        # Remember status and be quiet
        rc_status
        ;;
    restart)
        ## Stop the service and regardless of whether it was
        ## running or not, start it again.
        $0 stop
        $0 start
        haproxy_check
        # Remember status and be quiet
        rc_status
        ;;
    check)
        ## Stop the service and regardless of whether it was
        ## running or not, start it again.
        echo -n "Checking config of haproxy "
        haproxy_check
        rc_status -v
        ;;
    reload|force-reload)
        ## Like force-reload, but if daemon does not support
        ## signaling, do nothing (!)

        haproxy_check
        # If it supports signaling:
        echo -n "Reload service haproxy "
        $HAPROXY_BIN -p $HAPROXY_PID -D -f $HAPROXY_CONF -sf $(cat $HAPROXY_PID)
        rc_status -v
        ;;
    status)
        echo -n "Checking for service haproxy "
        ## Check status with checkproc(8), if process is running
        ## checkproc will return with exit status 0.

        # Return value is slightly different for the status command:
        # 0 - service up and running
        # 1 - service dead, but /var/run/  pid  file exists
        # 2 - service dead, but /var/lock/ lock file exists
        # 3 - service not running (unused)
        # 4 - service status unknown :-(
        # 5--199 reserved (5--99 LSB, 100--149 distro, 150--199 appl.)

        # NOTE: checkproc returns LSB compliant status values.
        /sbin/checkproc $HAPROXY_BIN
        # NOTE: rc_status knows that we called this init script with
        # "status" option and adapts its messages accordingly.
        rc_status -v
        ;;
    probe)
        ## Optional: Probe for the necessity of a reload, print out the
        ## argument to this init script which is required for a reload.
        ## Note: probe is not (yet) part of LSB (as of 1.9)

        test $HAPROXY_CONF -nt $HAPROXY_PID && echo reload
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|try-restart|restart|force-reload|reload|probe}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

I need 2 regexes that can match `haproxy_check` line only in 
1) `start)` and 
2) `restart)` code blocks.

I tried various things such as:

```
^\s*start\)(?:(?:(?:#|[ \t]+)[^\n]*|)\n)*?^\s*haproxy_check
```

The above one matches fine, but if `haproxy_check` is commented out, it errors out.

Any suggestions?

Thanks and regards,
Pravin Goyal

Comment: Which programming language are you using ? Post a complete example of the subject string.

Comment: From his example this looks like bash script.

Comment: @RoYoMi Where did the discussions go? Did you remove them?

Comment: I was getting sleepy which was keeping me from unwinding a catastrophic backtracking that was occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

**Special Note:**

I've taken creative liberty to include a serialized number on the `haproxy_check` substring, this is so help illustrate that we're capturing the desired instance. To remove this behavior simply remove the `_[0-9]` construct. The only difference between these two expressions is in the first couple of characters were I specify either `start` or `restart`.

**The Expressions**

```
\n\s*start\)(?:(?:(?![#"]|;;).)|\#[^\n]*\n|"[^"]*?")*?\K(haproxy_check_[0-9]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

```
\n\s*restart\)(?:(?:(?![#"]|;;).)|\#[^\n]*\n|"[^"]*?")*?\K(haproxy_check_[0-9]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- find the `haproxy_check` substring in the `start)` or `restart)` block respectively and place this into capture group 0. It's also included in capture group 1 so that highlighting works in the live demo. This behavior can be removed by removing the parentheses around `haproxy_check`
- only capture the `haproxy_check` from the start or restart blocks directly, do not accidentally pull the value from a trailing code block.
- will skip over lines that are commented out
- ignore comments following a `#`
- ignore `haproxy_check` when included inside a double quote block

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/yU3lK9/1

**Sample text**

I've boiled down the sample text from to include just what we're looking for and examples of what we're not looking for. And as noted above, I've added _ and numbers to serialize each `haproxy_check` for illustration purposes

```
case "$1" in
    start)
        # haproxy_check_01 ;;
        haproxy_check_02
        # haproxy_check_03 
        rc_status -v # haproxy_check_04
        echo " haproxy_check_05 "
        ;;
    stop)
        # haproxy_check_11
        haproxy_check_12
        # haproxy_check_13
        rc_status -v # haproxy_check_14
        echo " haproxy_check_15 "
        ;;
    try-restart|condrestart)
        # haproxy_check_21
        haproxy_check_22
        # haproxy_check_23
        rc_status -v # haproxy_check_24
        echo " haproxy_check_25 "
        ;;
    restart)
        # haproxy_check_31
        haproxy_check_32
        # haproxy_check_33
        rc_status -v # haproxy_check_34
        echo " haproxy_check_35 "
        ;;
    check)
        # haproxy_check_41
        haproxy_check_42
        # haproxy_check_43
        rc_status -v # haproxy_check_44
        echo " haproxy_check_45 "
        ;;
    reload|force-reload)
        # haproxy_check_51
        haproxy_check_52
        # haproxy_check_53
        rc_status -v # haproxy_check_54
        echo " haproxy_check_55 "
        ;;
    status)
        # haproxy_check_61
        haproxy_check_62
        # haproxy_check_63
        rc_status -v # haproxy_check_64
        echo " haproxy_check_65 "
        ;;
    probe)
        # haproxy_check_71
        haproxy_check_72
        # haproxy_check_73
        rc_status -v # haproxy_check_74
        echo " haproxy_check_75 "
        ;;
    *)
        # haproxy_check_81
        haproxy_check_82
        # haproxy_check_83
        rc_status -v # haproxy_check_84
        echo " haproxy_check_85 "
        ;;
    esac
```

**Sample Matches**

```
MATCH for the Start Block
1.  [56-72] `haproxy_check_02`

MATCH for the Restart block
1.  [563-579]   `haproxy_check_32`
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \n                       '\n' (newline)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  start                    'start'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [#"]                     any character of: '#', '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        ;;                       ';;'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .                        any character except \n
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \#                       '#'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\n]*                   any character except: '\n' (newline) (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \n                       '\n' (newline)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]*?                   any character except: '"' (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*?                      end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \K                       'K'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    haproxy_check_           'haproxy_check_'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks. This works awesome! One questions, can we do this with only the multiline modifier `m`? The tool that I am using, unfortunately, does not support `s` modifier.

Comment: The closest I am able to get is `^\s*start\)(?:(?:(?:#|[ \t]+)[^\n]*|)\n)*?\s+(haproxy_check)`. The problem is that if `haproxy_check` is commented out, it bleeds over to other code blocks. How do I restrict it `;;`?

Comment: The S option simply tells the regular expression engine to allow a dot to match new line characters. So simply replace the dot in my expression with something like `(?:[^a]|[a])` or `(?:\s|\S)` or `(?:.|[\r\n])` all of these would then behave as like a `.` with the S option. See also [this live demo](https://regex101.com/r/rR1dP2/1) that shows the regex with one of these modifications working without the S option.

Comment: You simply rock! Can't thank you enough for your help. Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 0):

This regex (you can see it live [here](https://regex101.com/r/uU7dR2/1)):

```
/^\s+(?:re)?start.*?(haproxy_check).*?;;/gsm
```

Will do the work.

It ensure that:

- The string start with spaces followed by `start` or `restart`
- It just capture one block, thanks to the lazyness of `.*?`
- The block contains `haproxy_check` (commented **or not**)

Comment: The core problem is that it should not match `haproxy_check` if it is commented out.